# after npm install gulp, suddenly no top folder "gulp"

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, directory, node-modules

After upgrading node (v6.11.1) and npm (5.2.0) i installed gulp. Before upgrading them, Gulp always was installed in a single folder named "gulp". Newly i've got 352 elements (folders) outspread in "node_modules". Anyway, everythings working, but now there's no clear view anymore about the order of all installed module folders.

[Screenshot folder "node_modules"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NLmr.jpg)

Does someone know why and how this can happen? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange.

You can use `npm la module` to see where it is. 
If you want to see al use `npm la`

For example, use `npm la gulp` to see where gulp is installed, maybe it could help you to understand what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I tried this and it's duly installed in my project folder. 

But not in a single folder "gulp", like it used to be before upgrading node and npm.